# Bootloader program that prints okay using nasm assembler

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, real-mode

So I was trying to run the program below using NASM assembler. Since I wanted to tell the assembler that I wanted a plain binary file without any bells nor whistles, I used:

> nasm -f -o boot.bin boot.asm
> Error:
> nasm fatal: unable to open input file 'boot.bin'

someone to please help out.Why did I get this error and how to solve it.

here is the code:

```
bits 16
start:
mov ax, 0x07C0     ;0x07C0 is where we are
add ax, 0x20       ;add 0x20 (when shifted 512)
mov ss,ax          ;set the stack segment
mov sp, 0x1000     ; set the stack pointer
mov ax, 0x07C0     ; set data segment
mov ds, ax         ;more about this later

mov si, msg        ;pointer to the message in SI
mov ah, 0x0E       ;print CHAR BIOS procedure

.next:
lodsb ;next byte to AL, increment SI
cmp al, 0 ;if the byte is zero
je .done ;jump do done
int 0x10 ;invoke the BIOS system call
jmp .next ;loop

.done:
jmp $ ;loop forever
msg: db 'ok',0  ;The string we want to print
times 510-($-$$) db 0  ;fill up to 510 bytes
dw 0xAA55 ;master boot record signature
```

Answer (score 2):

You specify **BIN**ary with the `-f bin` option in NASM. What you wanted was:

```
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm
```

The default is binary if you don't specify `-f` so this would have worked as well:

```
nasm -o boot.bin boot.asm
```